# What does this red triangle icon means on my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, icons

Does anyone know why i am getting this red triangle on my project in eclipse? thank you

[Red triangle on top of project's icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWG27.png)

Comment: Eclipse? I see PowerPoint there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see what you mean because the sceenshot is really crowded with stuff. But this site contains a lot of eclipse icons with explanation (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Comment: i updated the picture i am talking about the red triangle on the project's icon

Answer (score 0):

To find the problems you should open the problem view in eclipse, find the below snip[image]

View the probs related to project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The project has PMD violation(s).